# Disable browser access to Apache server directly from an IP

Tags: linux, apache

I have a server that I can access in my browser using the IP that my VPS provided.
I want to disable this. If someone tries to access directly from IP, they are redirected to the domain name URL of the website.

Example: inserting `https://90.32.34.32` and `http://90.32.34.32` goes directly to the website.

I have tried to change the `.htaccess` from the file.

Comment: Research some more here or on web, this is a classic case for apache configuration.